# How do I verify support for app blocks in PHP laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, shopify-app

In https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/verify-support they gave Node JS code example. I have Shopify app running in PHP Laravel based application. How do I verify support for app blocks in PHP laravel?

I saw this in ruby same I need in laravel [How do I verify support for app blocks in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742401/how-do-i-verify-support-for-app-blocks-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the NodeJS or Ruby code and convert it to PHP. As all scripting languages share very similar traits, you should have little to no trouble. PHP is so similar to Javascript, you should be able to do this little exercise. If not, well, there is a possibility you might find another developer to help you, one with more skills at scripting.

Comment: Thanks @david-lazar for your thoughts. I got the code from github - https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/issues/980 which is helpful for someone needy.